# Answer is always coming 0 regardless of parameters

Tags: c, function, floating-point, trigonometry

In the following program I'm trying to calculate the value of Sin(x) and Cos(x) using series formula [Sin(x),Cos(x) series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv30g.png) respectively. But answer is always coming 0. I'm trying it to solve without using pointers. And if you can please explain in elaborative way as i'm a beginner into coding.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int facto(int x)
{
    int i,ans;
  for(i=x;x>0;x--)
  {
      ans*=i;
  }
    return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
float pow(float x,int c)
{
    int o=0;
    float ans;
    while(o<c)
    {
        ans*=x;
        o++;
    }
    return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
float Sin(float x,int n)
{
  int i=1,j;
  float ans;
  while(i<=n)
  {
      if((j%2)==0)
      {
          ans+=(pow(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
      else
      {
          ans-=(pow(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
     i+=2;
     j++;
  }
  return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
float Cos(float x,int n)
{
  int i=0,j;
  float ans;
  while(i<=n)
  {
      if((j%2)==0)
      {
          ans+=(pow(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
      else
      {
          ans-=(pow(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
     i+=2;
     j++;
  }
  return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
int main ()
{
    int deg,cntr;
    float rad,ans;
    char s;
    printf("To calculate the value of sine function press  (s)  and for cosine function press  (c)  : ");
    scanf("%c",&s);
    printf("\nPlease provide value of angle in degree : ");
    scanf("%d",&deg);
    rad=(0.01745*deg);
    printf("\nPlease provide value for number of terms in series(more terms=more accuracy) : ");
    scanf("%d",&cntr);
    if((s=='S')||(s=='s'))
    {
      ans= Sin(rad,cntr);
      printf("\n\nThe value is %.5f \n\n",ans);
    }
    else if((s=='C')||(s=='c'))
    {
      ans= Cos(rad,cntr);
      printf("\n\nThe value is %.5f \n\n",ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program is riddled with undefined behavior because you never initialize `ans` with a value.

Comment: Your accuracy is limited by the very approximate value you are using for *pi* / 180. And why are you using `float` anyway? Always use `double` unless there is a very good reason why you can't use `float`. The `double` is the default floating point type for C. `1.234` is type `double`, the `%f` in `printf()` format expects `double`, the `pow()` library function returns a `double` (your version shares the standard C library function name), and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is a bit confusing but if you intend to compute factorial using the method `facto` that is wrong.

```
int facto(int x)
{
    int i,ans;
  for(i=x;x>0;x--)
  {
      ans*=i;
  }
    return ans;
}
```

Error:

- The code is updating `x` in the `for` loop and you are doing `ans *= i` where `i` is never changing. This would end up computing x^x and not x!.
- variable `ans` was defined not initialized that would lead to some garbage value in `ans` variable but it should be initialized to `1` instead.

2 ways to correct this,

1. Use `ans *= x;`

```
int facto(int x)
{
    int ans = 1;
  for(;x>0;x--)
  {
      ans*=x;
  }
    return ans;
}
```

2. Update `i` and not `x` in the `for` loop

```
int facto(int x)
{
    int i,ans = 1;
  for(i=x;i>0;i--)
  {
      ans*=i;
  }
    return ans;
}
```

Let me know if this works even though I see some other bugs as well.
Try to test functions & post function which have bugs rather than the entire code from the next time.

Comment: `"Try to test functions & post function which have bugs rather than the entire code from the next time."` -- The following official help page provides the exact guidelines: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int facto(int x)   // Calculates factorial
{
    int i,ans=1;
    for(i=1;i<=x;i++)
    {
        ans*=i;
    }
    return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
double powr(double x,int c) // Calculates x to the power c
{
    int o=0;
    double ans=1.00;
    for(o=0;o<c;o++)
    {
      ans*=x;
    }
    return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
double Sine(double x,int n) // Calculates sin(x)
{
  int i=1,j=0;
  double ans=0.0;
  while(i<=n)
  {
      if((j%2)==0)
      {
          ans+=(powr(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
      else
      {
          ans-=(powr(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
     i+=2;
     j++;
  }
  return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
double Cosine(double x,int n) // Calculate cos(x)
{
  int i=0,j=0;
  double ans=0.0;
  while(i<=n)
  {
      if((j%2)==0)
      {
          ans+=(powr(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
      else
      {
          ans-=(powr(x,i)/facto(i));
      }
     i+=2;
     j++;
  }
  return ans;
}
/***********************************************************************************************************************************************************/
int main()
{
    char d;
    int cntr;
    double deg;
    printf("Please provide value of angle in degree : ");
    scanf("%lf",&deg);
    double rad=deg*((22.0/7.0)*(1.0/180.0));
    printf("\nPlease provide value for number of terms in series (more terms=more accuracy) : ");
    scanf("%d",&cntr);
    printf("\nWrite \'c\' for cosine and \'s\' for sine : ");
    scanf(" %c",&d);
    if((d!='s')&&(d!='S')&&(d!='c')&&(d!='C'))

    {
        printf("\n\nNot a valid input, Please try again.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
      {
          if((d=='s')||(d=='S'))
          {
              printf("\n\nThe value is %.3f \n\n",Sine(rad,cntr));
          }
          else
            {
              printf("\n\nThe value is %.3f \n\n",Cosine(rad,cntr));
            }
      }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).